# How do I get the Proper Item in a Delphi DBLookupComboBox to be Selected

Tags: database, delphi, lookup

I have a **DBLookupComboBox** that is wired to a database query. That part is working fine. When I run the program the **DBLookupComboBox** is populated with the results of the query. I'd like to to see the **DBLookupComboBox** populated with the first item **"Please Select"** when the **program first runs** or when a **new item action is initiated**. (See below image)

[image]

Also, if I'm loading a previously saved database record that had selected **Index 2 "Quick Elimination"** how would I get the **DBLookupComboBox** to display that selected entry?

Yes, **"Please Select"** is index 0 and it is retreived as part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the value of the underlying table field is NULL rather than zero, which tells the DBComboBox that no value has yet been selected and it displays accordingly.

If the value in the table were zero, I thinkg the text in the edit field of the combo would be selected to indicate that, but I may recall this incorrectly.

Anyway, just check for Field1.IsNull (or IsEmpty) and then set it to zero. It does mean that you can no longer distinguish between an "unknown value" (NULL) and "no selected value" (zero), unless you prevent the zero value from making it back into the table...

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I've been away from Delphi programming for quite a while (8+ years) and have spent most of my time web programming. When I started web programming I remember being very frustrated until I fully understood the concept of a stateless environment. Now I'm getting back into Delphi and I'm frustrated because I'm trying to employ a "stateless coding style" to DBControls that are not stateless.

Comment: @Cape: Wellcome back to Delphi. Hope it isn't all frustration for you and there are at least a couple of "oh yeah!"'s around.

Comment: I just had one of those "oh yeah!" moments. I purchased Cary Jensens new book "Delphi in Depth: ClienDataSets" and have been porting his BDE-DBDEMOS examples over to MS Access and learning a lot. ClientDataSets have a lot of usefulness. When I get done with porting to Access, I'm going try porting over to ElevateDB.

Answer (score 9):

You could try this (I know you've probably solved it by now, as you asked over 2 years ago), but in case anyone else was interested...

```
dbluLookup.KeyValue := dbluLookup.ListSource.DataSet.FieldByName(dbluLookup.KeyField).Value;
```

That simply sets KeyValue to the first record in the ListSource dataset, which should be the row 'Please Select'.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to add 'Please select' to the underlying table from which you are selecting, where the key to this tuple would be 0. Then when you display the combobox and the value of the connected field is 0, 'Please select' would be displayed. Of course, you have to make sure that this value is never selected!

Comment: Then you have to ensure that the fields of a new record are initialised to value 0 and not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The `DBLookupComboBox` displays by default the `ListField(s)` whose `KeyField` in the `ListSource` matches the `DataField` in the `DataSource`. So, to ensure to display some value for the `DataField` being NULL, you have to provide a `KeyField` of NULL in the `ListSource`. But one could imagine not wanting a NULL value in the underlaying table associated to the `ListSource`.

One way to circumvent this is to add the NULL value to the dataset behind the `ListSource` with a `UNION SELECT`. That should work just fine, since that dataset does not have to be editable.

Now, to assure this special dataset is only available when you are adding a new record to the dataset associated to the `DataSource`, manage the query for `ListSource.DataSet` in `DataSource.OnStateChange`. When `DataSource.State = dsInsert`, then update `ListSource.DataSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Modification for Steve Childs answer in TwwDBLookupCombo, InfoPower component

```
cboFilterTravel1.LookupValue := cboFilterTravel1.LookupTable.FieldByName(cboFilterTravel1.LookupField).Value;
```

Thanks Steve It's works for me