# DBLookup Combobox not binding null values

Tags: delphi, combobox, dataset

I've got a similar problem to this question. 
[How do I get the Proper Item in a Delphi DBLookupComboBox to be Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212216/how-do-i-get-the-proper-item-in-a-delphi-dblookupcombobox-to-be-selected)

I have DBLookupcombox that displays a Lookup field from my dataset. But for some reason my lookup field ( or combobox ) is not binding then null-value keys and the combobox is empty.

This is my list source

[image]

This is my data source

[image]

This is the field definition

[image]

This is the result I get

[image]

I don't really understand why the binding is not working for null values but it does work for the other values.

Comment: [NULL is not a value](http://petercai.com/null-is-not-a-value/).

Comment: Maybe the comment by @OndrejKelle should become an answer. And here is further info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080085/how-to-allow-selecting-a-null-value-in-a-tdblookupcombobox