# How to allow selecting a NULL value in a TDBLookupComboBox?

Tags: delphi, combobox, null, dataset

I have a `TDBLookupComboBox` showing a `TStringField` of kind `fkLookup`, which allows `Null` values (from a nullable Integer database column).

The dropdown list displays the items from the assigned `LookupDataSet`, which comes from a joined table. If the field is `Null`, none of the list items are displayed, the combobox is empty. If the field has a value, the correct description is shown.

I can reset it to `Null` by pressing the assigned `NullValueKey`.

That's all ok, but the users prefer using the mouse. So I could provide a clear button, but I think an additional row on top of the list would be much better. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the empty row in your query, and if you need it sorted you can make it appear at the top in your list like this:

```
select 0 as sort,
       convert(int, null) as UserID,
       'Clear' as Name
union all
select 1 as sort,
       u.UserID,
       u.Name
from   tblUser u
order by sort, Name
```

The `sort` column will make it appear at the top, after that you can sort on whatever you need.

Comment: That looks hackish to me and that "clear" item doesn't work very consistently: clicking it empties the combobox and sets the field to null, but when you open the dropdown list again, no list entry would appear selected like it would with normal entries. I'm accepting this, because it seems there is no better solution using standard `TDBLookupComboBox`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use as your `LookupDataSet` a query with the next SQL (Firebird syntax)

```
SELECT CAST (NULL AS INTEGER) AS ID, CAST ('clear' AS VARCHAR(80)) AS NAME FROM table_name
UNION
SELECT ID, NAME FROM table_name
```

However, in this implementation `clear` item will be at the end of the list.

**Added after our discussion in the chat**

I'm afraid we never reach to have null-value field's behavior like *normal* fields, because null is not a value, as was correctly mentioned here: https://petercai.com/null-is-not-a-value/ . We can only make some workarounds for it.

For example, we can see custom displayed value for null such as `SELECT CASE WHEN OurField IS NULL THEN '(empty)' ELSE OurField END AS OurField`. And we can set null with artificial menu item. But this is not a full, complex solution.

Comment: Are you sure this would work like expected? I cannot try it exactly like this, because my DataSet cannot come from a SQL query in this case.
Maybe I could add a Null row using some other way, but in some other question it looks like doing this is not enough and it wouldn't behave like a normal value in the combobox.

Comment: This is the question I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606879/dblookup-combobox-not-binding-null-values

Comment: I tested it. If you select `clear` in dropdown menu, null will be written in db field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess you tested also the other way round, so you can also reply to that old question above?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm not familiar with how lookup fields work (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182858/discussion-between-miamy-and-maf-soft).

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what was requested, but it might be **the** better solution for developers having a *DevExpress* VCL ExpressEditors subscription: there is a hidden feature in `TcxDBLookupComboBox` which can provide a nice clear button inside the combobox!

[image: Screenshot of a TcxDBLookupComboBox/IsFixedList with clear button]

It works exactly like in the `TcxButtonEdit`, where you can add buttons at designtime, just that this `Buttons` property isn't exposed in `TcxDBLookupComboBox`, so it can only be set at runtime :(

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddClearButton(cxDBLookupComboBox1.Properties);
end;

procedure TForm1.AddClearButton(Prop: TcxCustomEditProperties);
begin
  with Prop.Buttons.Add do begin
    Kind:= bkText;
    Caption:= #$2715; //Unicode X-symbol
  end;
  Prop.OnButtonClick:= ClearButtonClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.ClearButtonClick(Sender: TObject; AButtonIndex: Integer);
begin
  if AButtonIndex = 1 then
    with TcxCustomEdit(Sender) do begin
      EditValue:= Null;
      PostEditValue;
    end;
end;
```

This might also work with other edit controls, however, at least with TcxDBSpinEdit it does not.

Comment: With the devexpress controls I think you can also do ctrl-delete to clear the combobox

Comment: That's also possible in the standard combobox. I mentioned this already in the question (`NullValueKey` property).